# Error when encoding with Azure Media Encoder

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I am using Azure Media Services Explorer to encode a 1080p video. When I have my reserved media units set to 0, everything works, but the encoding takes about 5 hours.

When I scale the MRUs to anything (S1, S2, S3) after about 10 minutes of the job sitting in a "Queued" state, I get an error:

```
Reached the max retry count limit for evaluating SLA for this task.
```

I don't understand what could be wrong. Feels like an outage or an issue on their end. Anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting this - are you using an account in US East 2 region? It appears at first glance that there's been a provisioning error. I have asked our live site support team to investigate. In the meantime, would it be possible to move to a different region?

If you need further details, please contact us directly via amshelp@microsoft.com

Thanks

Comment: Anil, thanks for the reply. Yes I am. This is the second time I've had a "provisioning error" with the east us2 region. The other time was with a live event that wouldn't start. After reaching out to support they fixed it. Is there something that makes this region unreliable?

Comment: Per my colleague: the Media Services deployment in this region was intended for limited operation until sufficient resources were added. While we are working with appropriate teams to address this, you may want to use an account in another region.

Comment: Thanks Anil. What region do you think would be best for production, mission critical events and media? We are located in GA, USA